# call method from another class generating SIGABRT error on xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am calling a method contained on a controller class that have to change views. It generates an error on insertsubview.view. How to solve it? Thank you

call from current menuViewController class:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
     aboutTabController * myObject = [[aboutTabController alloc] init];

    if (indexPath.section == 1) {

        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                [myObject turnIdioma];
                break;
            case 1:
                //
                break;
            default:
            break;}
    }

}

//method implememented in controller class:

- (void) turnIdioma
{


     [UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    if (self.controladorAjustes == nil)
    {
        settingsViewController *aController = [[settingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mailViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.controladorAjustes = aController;
        [aController release];
    }

    [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];

    [self.controladorMenu viewWillDisappear:YES];
    [self.controladorAjustes viewWillAppear:YES];

    [self.controladorMenu.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view insertSubview:controladorAjustes.view    atIndex:0];

    [self.controladorMenu viewDidDisappear:YES];
    [self.controladorAjustes viewDidAppear:YES];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Check the value of controladorAjusted.view before you insert it as a subview. Is it possible that it is nil?

Comment: yes, it is nil. View from class who calls that method must be removed when method is executed, could it be a problem?

Comment: ok, solved, was only an when calling xib! name was not correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert a nil valued object as a subview. Typically the view controller will make sure it is created when you try to get its view property, using the appropriate method depending on whether it is a view defined by a NIB file or not.

IF you are doing something to explicitly set the view to nil then you are probably not taking the right approach. I suspect you are doing something fishy inside your call to:

```
  [self.controladorAjustes viewWillAppear:YES];
```